# Move Delegates to their own classes?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, delegates

My view controller is getting a little large for me. I'm implementing five delegate protocols and was about to add a sixth.

```
ABCViewController : UITableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,
                                          UITableViewDelegate,
                                          UITableViewDataSource,
                                          UIAlertViewDelegate,
                                          CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

One controller to implement them all seems ridiculous, but they aren't being used anywhere else. Should these be in their own classes or in the view controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add categories to ABCViewController, like this:

**1. Move any declarations in ABCViewController.m into a private category in ABCViewController.h**

```
// in ABCViewController.h
@interface ABCViewController : UIViewController <delegates>
// anything that's in the _public_ interface of this class.
@end

@interface ABCViewController ()
// anything that's _private_ to this class.  Anything you had defined in the .m previously
@end
```

**2. ABCViewController.m should include that .h.**

**3. Then in ABCViewController+SomeDelegate.h and .m**

```
// in ABCViewController+SomeDelegate.h
@interface ABCViewController (SomeDelegateMethods)

@end

// in ABCViewController+SomeDelegate.m
#import "ABCViewController+SomeDelegate.h"
#import "ABCViewController.h"  // here's how will get access to the private implementation, like the _fetchedResultsController

@implementation ABCViewController (SomeDelegateMethods)

// yada yada

@end
```

Comment: I really like the idea of putting the delegate methods in categories, but I'm having trouble with the FetchedResultsController ivar. I think. The error is that the category is trying to access `__fetchedResultsController` and not finding it. I'm still kinda shaky on Core data, so I don't know where it was declared for the main class, except the `@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController` This is what I get for using the template without complete understanding.

Comment: It's probably declared inside the ABC view controller .m, making it invisible to the category file.  I think the way to go here is a (gulp) private category declared in the public header.  Will edit my answer to be more thorough...

Comment: Ive done this except for instead of private props in the header ive created a private header file, which contains that private interface, bit in the body of my class+UITableview i cannot access self.tableView for example, feeling thats ive missed a step, is (someDelegateMethods) supposed to be <UITableviewDelegate....>?

Answer (score 2):

You can also declare conformity to that protocol in the .m file like this:

```
@interface ABCViewController (NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegateMethods) <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@end
@implementation ABCViewController (NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegateMethods)
...
@end
```

This won't make your file shorter but at least it will be clearly divided into parts

If you are using Xcode you can try something like this for example:

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegateMethods
```

Quite handy to find your methods like in this [tip: Pragma mark](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.jp/2006/09/tip-pragma-mark-organizing-your-source.html)

---

Alternatively, depending on what you do the delegate methods and how structured is your code you could have another object that has only methods of the delegate protocol

```
@interface Delegate <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> : NSObject
@end
```

You would have an instance of this object as an ivar in your ABCViewController.

Comment: I've been doing the pragma to mark :) it's been the only thing keeping the controller navigable